# Sudden CSS styling issue only on Safari on iPhone

Tags: ios, css, safari

Trying to help troubleshoot an issue with a charity's web site and it appears that the site's CSS is only partially loading when viewed on Safari. A short link to the site is http://bit.ly/1znipeN

I've used the W3C CSS validator on the child theme CSS and it validated ok, less a couple of warnings. The odd thing is that the site appeared to be working fine until today. I wonder whether it could be a temporary issue in a 3rd party resource, such as JSQuery or similar that is causing Safari not to render correctly? It works fine in Chrome for example.

Is there any way of debugging it to try and find the cause?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done so yet clear cache in Safari and Chrome and reload to check if the error is possibly now gone or visible in multiple browsers.

If you are using versioning such as git:
Undo all changes that have been made today (and maybe also yesterday) and test again. If the site works now on Safari, take the changes back in one by one and test which one breaks the layout.

If you use a preprocessor such as Sass, compare the size of yesterday's CSS file to the current one. If it is smaller there might be an error in rendering the file.

Hope one of these helps.

Comment: Thanks, yes have cleared caching both client and server side. Nothing has changed over night in terms of versions of files (although they don't use anything like git - it's just a straight forward Wordpress site).

Answer (score 0):

Ah interesting, so these lines we added to .htaccess were the cause for the site not to render correctly in Safari, Firefox and a few others (worked fine in Chrome).

```
<filesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
Header set Content-Encoding x-deflate
# Header set Content-Encoding compress
# Header set Content-Encoding x-gzip
</filesMatch>
```